# R error in mutate_impl of column length

Tags: r, error-handling, calculated-columns, dplyr

I have a data frame and I am trying to add a Total column and sum each row to fill the Total.  I have done this previously in my script and not had a problem, but now I am getting an error when I run.  The data frame is 39 variables and 3142 obs.  It starts with a character column with the county fips code and then is followed by 38 columns of numeric data with population by sex and 5 year age groups.  I need to sum the rows to get the total population for each county.  A short version of the data frame is:

```
GEOID  FU5  MU5  F5to9  M5to9  F10to14  M10to14
01001   50   50     45     45       48       48
01002   15   15     20     20       18       18
```

The script I have is:

```
 df <- df %>%
    mutate(df_Total = rowSums(df[,c(2:39)]))
```

The error message I keep getting is:

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
   Column `Pop2020_Total` must be length 1 (the group size), not 3142
```

As I said, I use this same script several times earlier in my script to get the total column in data frames.  I didn't include the ,na.rm = TRUE in the script because I have made sure that there are no NA values.  Any ideas why this is not working would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The `c2` seems to be a typo

```
df %>%
   mutate(df_Total = rowSums(.[,2:39]))
```

Comment: Sorry.  That was a typo.  It should have read mutate(df_Total = rowSums(df[,c(2:39)])).  I will correct that in the question.  However, your answer does not fix it.  I still get the same error message.